# If statement missing ( in function main. cant get passed this error

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int khm;

printf("Please enter how fast the vehicle was going in km//h: ");
scanf("%d%*c", &khm);

    if khm>60 khm<65
    {
        printf("Issue a warning: ");
    }   
    else

        if khm>65 khm<70    
        {
            printf("Issue a fine of $80: ");
        }   
        else

            if khm>70 khm<80
            {
                printf("Issue a fine of $150: ");
            }   
            else

                if khm>80
                {
                    printf("Issue a fine of $500: ");
                }   
                else
                {
                    printf("This vehicle is not speeding: ");
                }

        return(0);
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to parenthesize the expression evaluated by the if statement `if (khm>60 && khm<65)` etc. Even a bad C tutorial should cover that.

Comment: C is not the same a Go.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
{
 int khm;

 printf("Please enter how fast the vehicle was going in     km//h: ");
 // error  
 scanf("%d", &khm);
// this is how we should write..
if (khm>60 && khm<65)
{
    printf("Issue a warning: ");
}   
else

    if (khm>65 && khm<70)
    {
        ("Issue a fine of $80: ");
    }   
    else

        if( khm>70 &&  khm<80)
        {
            printf("Issue a fine of $150: ");
        }   
        else

            if( khm>80)
            {
                printf("Issue a fine of $500: ");
            }   
            else
            {
                printf("This vehicle is not speeding: ");
            }

    return(0);
 }
```

Comment: Don't forget to end the output with a newline.  Normally, you don't end statements with a colon, either.  A full stop, or no punctuation would be correct.  Or, perish the thought, an exclamation mark.

Comment: Also, trekking off the right-hand side of the page like that is not the standard layout in C.  You can avoid the double tests by checking for `khm <= 60` first and printing 'This vehicle is not speeding' if that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact you didn't use parantheses `()`, 
This is the correct syntax for an `AND` operator in C:

```
if ((khm > 60) && (khm < 65))
{
   // code
}
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of parentheses. Very LISP like code :)

Comment: @StoryTeller lol... I am used to write very clear code. Maybe messy for others, very organized for me...

Answer (score 0):

- `if khm>60 khm<65`
- `if khm>65 khm<70`
- `if khm>70 khm<80`
- `if khm>80`

These 3 if-statements are syntactically incorrect for 2 reasons:

**Firstly**:

> If statement missing ( in function main

The compiler is telling you in this error message that you need to use parentheses (like `()`) to enclose the conditional statement of an if-statement. In general, this also applies while-loop condition statements and for-loop condition statements.

**Secondly**, in the if-statements where you have multiple conditions (like `khm>70 khm<80`), you need to specify a logical AND or OR operator in between these 2 conditions. These 2 conditions tell the compiler whether you want both the conditions satisfied to enter the body of the if-statement (this is done with the AND operator), or you simply want one of these conditions to be satisfied (this is done with the OR operator).

- The AND operator has the following symbol: `&&`
- The OR operator has the following symbol: `||`

Judging from your case, you will need the `&&` operator.

As an aside, you can shorten your code a lot and make it easier to read of you put the else and if-statement on the same line. Instead of doing:

```
else
    if (khm > 65 && khm < 70)
```

You can do:

```
else if (khm > 65 && khm < 70)
```

Therefore, change your code to:

```
if (khm > 60 && khm < 65)
    // Add your code here   

else if (khm > 65 && khm < 70)    
    // Add your code here

else if (khm > 70 && khm < 80)
    // Add your code here  

else if (khm > 80)
    // Add your code here   

else
    // Add your code here
```